ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain' in docker container
I am building a Langchain/Langserve app.
It is working fine on my Mac and I can start it locally (with langchain serve).
However, when I build the container (from the docker file that was generated by Langserve) and start the container on AWS Margate, it get the following error:
"Langchain: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain' "
I suspect it is to do with a path not defined properly when building the container but not being an expert in docker and am not sure how to check or correct it.
Any guidance welcome.
Below is the docker file:
FROM python:3.11.5-bookworm


ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

ENV LISTEN_PORT 8080

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN pip install poetry==1.6.1

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false


WORKDIR /code

COPY ./pyproject.toml ./README.md ./poetry.lock* ./

COPY ./package[s] ./packages

RUN poetry install  --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root

COPY ./app ./app

RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

EXPOSE 8080

CMD exec uvicorn app.server:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

The pyproject.toml is as below:
[tool.poetry]
name = "pdfbot"
version = "0.0.1"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8.1,<4.0"
langchain-core = ">=0.1.5"
langchain-openai = ">=0.0.1"
huggingface-hub = "^0.20.3"
pytest = "^8.0.0"
pypdf = "^4.0.1"
sentence-transformers = "^2.3.1"
chromadb = "^0.4.22"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
langchain-cli = ">=0.0.4"
fastapi = "^0.104.0"
sse-starlette = "^1.6.5"

[tool.langserve]
export_module = "pdfbot"
export_attr = "chain"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

And the poetry.lock also contains Langchain:
[[package]]
name = "langchain"
version = "0.1.5"
description = "Building applications with LLMs through composability"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.8.1,<4.0"
files = [
    {file = "langchain-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:4614118d4a95b2e7ba3611a0b6b21707a259a21652a04fbe3c31205bcf3fcd50"},
    {file = "langchain-0.1.5.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:69603a5bb21b044ddea69d38131dbbf47475afdf79728644faa67d1ad325d652"},
]

[package.dependencies]
aiohttp = ">=3.8.3,<4.0.0"
async-timeout = {version = ">=4.0.0,<5.0.0", markers = "python_version < \"3.11\""}
dataclasses-json = ">=0.5.7,<0.7"
jsonpatch = ">=1.33,<2.0"
langchain-community = ">=0.0.17,<0.1"
langchain-core = ">=0.1.16,<0.2"
langsmith = ">=0.0.83,<0.1"
numpy = ">=1,<2"
pydantic = ">=1,<3"
PyYAML = ">=5.3"
requests = ">=2,<3"
SQLAlchemy = ">=1.4,<3"
tenacity = ">=8.1.0,<9.0.0"

I did build a container locally using same docker file that was working fine but my company removed my local docker instance so I moved the build process to GitLab.
I have now re-installed Docker locally and built the container again but also get the same error.
I am really puzzled as I can run the app locally and it works, its only when building the container that something seems to be missing...
Many thanks in advance

Is langchain listed in the pyproject.toml under the packages?
If it is, is langchain included in the poetry.lock file?

Why do you run poetry install twice?

I do not see langchain mentioned anywhere in this dockerfile.  How is it being installed?

Yes langchain is listed in pyproject.toml, it is also in the poetry.lock file
